# Канал Telegram не обновляется

Tags: telegram

Информация в Telegram-канале перестала обновляться до того момента, пока сам принудительно не сфокусируюсь на нём. Например, собственный бот только что отправил туда сообщение. Но ни мобильная, ни настольная версия нового сообщения не видят. Как только выберу этот канал мышкой или тапом пальца в списке контактов, то спустя пару секунд подгружаются новые сообщения. В чём может быть проблема?

Есть иллюстративная гифка - https://i.imgur.com/qEPtIxK.gifv

Comment: `UNMUTE` попробуй нажать

Comment: Пробовал. Не спасает.
Ещё была попытка поставить, например, Challegram. Бестолку.

Comment: отправь чтонить сейчас, просто интересно у тебя у одного так или у всех

Comment: Готово. Сообщение упало в канал. О статистике Steam.

Comment: Все ок, нотификация робит

Comment: Ну это единственный такой канал. С остальными проблем нет. Ещё вариантом видится удаления себя из канала, но я там создатель и админ.